# OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager

При переключении фрагментов обновляются записи в БД.

Для переключения фрагментов используется `PagerAdapter`
Есть 4 фрагмента `position 0 - 3`, При переключении с 0 в 1, с 1 в 2 и т.д. всё работает, но при "обратном" переключении (с 2 в 1) ничего не происходит.

Всё просиходит в `OnPageScrolled`, пробывал в `OnPageSelected` - так же не работает корректно. Если убрать `oldPosition` - ничего не изменится.

Вот код приложения(не полный, дабы не забивать лишней инфой):

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();


        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        id = intent.getStringExtra("_id");
        Log.d(TAG, "get from intent name:" + name + " id:" + id);


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }



    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = null;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    title = "Users";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title =  "System";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title =  "IO";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    title = "Other Text";
                    break;
            }
            return title;
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (position == 0){
//--------------------------------------------Users Tab---------------------------------------------
            db = new DB(this);
            db.open();

            userp2 = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.user_phone_2_et);
            userp3 = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.user_phone_3_et);
            userp4 = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.user_phone_4_et);
            i1_notif_1 = (CheckBox) pager.findViewById(R.id.i1_notification_1);
            /*.....
            .......
            .......*/

            userp2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    userp2s = "01" + userp2.getText().toString() + "%";
                }
            });
            /*.....
            .......
            .......*/

            if (i1_notif_1.isChecked()) i1_notif1s = "1"; else i1_notif1s = "0";
            /*.....
            .......
            .......*/


            if (OldPosition != position) {
                db.SystemUpdRec(name, calltimes.getText().toString(), workmodes, power_analise_s, lifepulse.getText().toString(), moneynumb.getText().toString(), ok1s, ok2s, entrys, exits, id);
                db.SystemSMSUpdRec(name, calltimess, workmodes, power_analise_s, lifepulses, moneynubs, ok1s, ok2s, entrys, exits, id);
                OldPosition = position;
            }

            db.close();
        }

//--------------------------------------------System Tab--------------------------------------------
        if (position == 1) {
            db = new DB(this);
            db.open();
            calltimes = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.call_times_et);
            lifepulse = (EditText) pager.findViewById(R.id.life_pulse_et);
            /*.....
            .......
            .......*/
          
            calltimes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    calltimess = "08" + calltimes.getText().toString() + "%";
                }
            });

            workmode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case R.id.free_work:
                            workmodes = "090%";
                            break;
                        case R.id.daily_alarm:
                            workmodes = "091%";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

           if (OldPosition == 0) {

                db.UserUpdRec(name, userp2.getText().toString(), userp3.getText().toString(), userp4.getText().toString(), i1_notif1s, i2_notif1s, i3_notif1s, i4_notif1s, i5_notif1s, lp_notif1s, money_notif1s, reboot_notif1s, pulse_notif1s,
                        i1_notif2s, i2_notif2s, i3_notif2s, i4_notif2s, i5_notif2s, lp_notif2s, money_notif2s, reboot_notif2s, pulse_notif2s,
                        i1_notif3s, i2_notif3s, i3_notif3s, i4_notif3s, i5_notif3s, lp_notif3s, money_notif3s, reboot_notif3s, pulse_notif3s,
                        i1_notif4s, i2_notif4s, i3_notif4s, i4_notif4s, i5_notif4s, lp_notif4s, money_notif4s, reboot_notif4s, pulse_notif4s,
                        id);
                db.UserSMSUpdRec(name, userp2s, userp3s, userp4s, i1_notif1s, i2_notif1s, i3_notif1s, i4_notif1s, i5_notif1s, lp_notif1s, money_notif1s, reboot_notif1s, pulse_notif1s,
                        i1_notif2s, i2_notif2s, i3_notif2s, i4_notif2s, i5_notif2s, lp_notif2s, money_notif2s, reboot_notif2s, pulse_notif2s,
                        i1_notif3s, i2_notif3s, i3_notif3s, i4_notif3s, i5_notif3s, lp_notif3s, money_notif3s, reboot_notif3s, pulse_notif3s,
                        i1_notif4s, i2_notif4s, i3_notif4s, i4_notif4s, i5_notif4s, lp_notif4s, money_notif4s, reboot_notif4s, pulse_notif4s,
                        id);
            }
            if (OldPosition == 2) {
                db.InpOutUpdRec(name, i1_rt.getText().toString(), i2_rt.getText().toString(), i3_rt.getText().toString(), i4_rt.getText().toString(),
                        i1_ac_s, i2_ac_s, i3_ac_s, i4_ac_s, i5_ac_s,
                        i1_rc_s, i2_rc_s, i3_rc_s, i4_rc_s, i5_rc_s,
                        i1_as_s, i2_as_s, i3_as_s, i4_as_s, i5_as_s,
                        i1_rs_s, i2_rs_s, i3_rs_s, i4_rs_s, i5_rs_s,
                        i1_ii_s, i2_ii_s, i3_ii_s, i4_ii_s,
                        i5pswrd.getText().toString(),
                        z1_alarm.getText().toString(), z2_alarm.getText().toString(), z3_alarm.getText().toString(), z4_alarm.getText().toString(), arm.getText().toString(),
                        z1_restore.getText().toString(), z2_restore.getText().toString(), z3_restore.getText().toString(), z4_restore.getText().toString(), disarm.getText().toString(),
                        id);
                db.InpOutSMSUpdRec(name, i1_rt_s, i2_rt_s, i3_rt_s, i4_rt_s,
                        i1_ac_s, i2_ac_s, i3_ac_s, i4_ac_s, i5_ac_s,
                        i1_rc_s, i2_rc_s, i3_rc_s, i4_rc_s, i5_rc_s,
                        i1_as_s, i2_as_s, i3_as_s, i4_as_s, i5_as_s,
                        i1_rs_s, i2_rs_s, i3_rs_s, i4_rs_s, i5_rs_s,
                        i1_ii_s, i2_ii_s, i3_ii_s, i4_ii_s,
                        i5pswrd_s, z1_alarm_s, z2_alarm_s, z3_alarm_s, z4_alarm_s, arm_s,
                        z1_restore_s, z2_restore_s, z3_restore_s, z4_restore_s, disarm_s,
                        id);
            }
            OldPosition = position;
            db.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }
```

Comment: что значит ваше `ничего не происходит`? Не вызывается метод лиснера? Вы ы этом уверены?

Comment: @metalurgus метод вызывается, но RadioGroup и CheckBox неправильно сохраняются, надо перейти со страницы, вернуться, и опять перейти с неё